# Not found error on setting up local server using LAMPP

Tags: lampp

When I enter localhost/hello.php in my browser, I get below error.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /hello.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: -Removed index.php; changed port configuration;restarting apache server etc...I have done set-up through this tutorial: http://www.codingdevil.com/2014/02/how-to-run-xampp-on-ubuntu.html#comment-5782

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some compatibility issue in the LAMPP and Ubuntu.

To start apache2 normally you need to first hard stop it through following command:

Sudo service apache2 stop.

And then restart the apache2 or LAMPP . This worked for me.